# select by aggregation of fields in json column and sum

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, sum, jsonb

Using postgresql 11.

Given the following dataset:

```
        foo        |   bar    
-------------------+--------------------------------------------------
         "a"       | {'a_count': 1, 'b_count': 2, 'c_count': 3}::jsob
         "b"       | {'a_count': 2, 'b_count': 3}::jsob
(2 rows)
```

I'd like to collect the following result:

```
    foo   |   a_count    |    b_count     |     c_count     
----------------------------------------------------------  
    "a"   |       3      |       5        |         3
```

Without having to specifically query for every possible item in the jsonb column (ideally aggregate them all at once).

What's the best way to achieve that? And possible performance impact?

Comment: "*Without having to specifically query for every possible item in the jsonb column*" - not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the name, type and number of all columns of a SELECT statement must be known to the database before the data is retrieved. It's not possible to have a SELECT query that returns a different set of columns each time you run it.

Comment: been digging the problem some more, and found **jsonb_to_recordset** . So I can return a different set of columns, it seems. that would give me all the entries, and no the sum though, so I'm looking at how to combine that in order to aggregate and sum those values.

Comment: You still need to provide the names and types returned by `jsonb_to_recordset`

Comment: On what basis is does the output have "a"?